# Saving & Testing Stored Procedures/Triggers (maybe User Defined Functions) For Partitioned Collections

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm receiving the following error when attempting save modifications to a Stored Procedure that has been created within a partitioned collection:

> **Failed to save the script**

Here is the details from within the Azure Portal:

> Operation name Failed to save the script Time stamp Fri Feb 17 2017
>   08:46:32 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) Event initiated by
>   - Description Database Account: MyDocDbAccount, Script: bulkImport, Message: {"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"***Replaces
>   and upserts for scripts in collections with multiple partitions are
>   not supported***.

The Stored Procedure in question is the example "bulkImport" script that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-programming#example-bulk-importing-data-into-a-database-program).

Comment: Seems like it's pretty self-explanatory, that you can't do a replacement on it (and, logically, that you'd need to do a delete, and then an add). No?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a known missing capability (bug, if you prefer) in DocumentDB right now where you cannot update existing stored procedures in a partitioned collection. The workaround is to delete it first and then recreate it under the same name/id.

Comment: Thx Larry! After spending some time doing just that, I decided to spend a few moments to put this out to the community.

Comment: going with delete and recreate might lead to downtime during any deployment ! How about Create always and ignore if it all ready exist, for any changes in SP, the only approach left is to change the SP name if one need no downtime deployment and multiple instances of services running !

Comment: @SurenderSinghMalik Note that, looking at the response when creating a SP, there is a quota on how many different SPs can be created inside a collection, and the default seems to be 100 - if you keep creating new SPs, you may hit that quota rather quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to the error message, it turns out that `_client.ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync(...)` does work (as of June 2018) on partitioned collections. So you can do something like this:

```
try 
{
    await _client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(...);
} 
catch(DocumentClientException dex) when (dex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict) 
{ 
    await _client.ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync(...);  
}
```

Once your SP gets created the 1st time, you will never have any time quanta when it isn't available (due to deletion + recreation).

Comment: Yes, support for replacing scripts in partitioned collection was added around beginning of year 2018.

Comment: @MichaelKoltachev I still received this error with latest client in 03/2019.

Comment: @Jazaret - Make sure that you are using the most up to date version of the CosmosDB SDK.  I have verified that this works as of today.

Answer (score 0):

This extension method can handle add or update of a stored procedure.

```
public static async Task AddOrUpdateProcedure(this DocumentClient client, 
    string databaseId, 
    string collectionId, 
    string storedProcedureId, 
    string storedProcedureBody)
{
    try
    {
        var documentCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
        await client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(documentCollectionUri, new StoredProcedure
        {
            Id = storedProcedureId,
            Body = storedProcedureBody
        });
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
    {
        var storedProcedureUri = UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(databaseId, collectionId, storedProcedureId);
        var storedProcedure = await client.ReadStoredProcedureAsync(storedProcedureUri);
        storedProcedure.Resource.Body = storedProcedureBody;
        await client.ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync(storedProcedure);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, updating a stored procedure still does not work in Azure Portal / CosmosDB Data explorer.  There is a Cosmos DB Extension for Visual Studio Code where this works.  However I don't see a way of executing the procedure from the extension like I can from Data Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  try
                    {
                        var spResponse = await dbClient.CreateStoredProcedureAsync($"/dbs/{dataRepoDatabaseId}/colls/{collectionName}", new StoredProcedure
                        {
                            Id = sp.Item1,
                            Body = sp.Item2
                        }, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) });

                    }
                    catch (DocumentClientException dex) when (dex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                    {
                        //Fetch the resource to be updated
                        StoredProcedure sproc = dbClient.CreateStoredProcedureQuery($"/dbs/{dataRepoDatabaseId}/colls/{collectionName}")
                                                         .Where(r => r.Id == sp.Item1)
                                                         .AsEnumerable()
                                                         .SingleOrDefault();
                        if(!sproc.Body.Equals( sp.Item2))
                        {
                            sproc.Body = sp.Item2;

                            StoredProcedure updatedSPResponse = await dbClient.ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync(sproc);

                        }
                    }
```