# Unable to update a CosmosDB stored procedure in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Just starting with CosmosDB.  I am trying to write a stored procedure for my CosmosDB data in the Azure portal (Data Explorer). I am able to create a new stored procedure and execute it, but I am unable to save any changes to the procedure.  When I try, I get the following error message:

```
Error while updating stored procedure testSP:
...
Create, update, or delete scripts in direct mode in collections with multiple partitions is not allowed.
```

Not sure what `direct mode` means.  How do I get around this?

Comment: This is a temporary error that is happening on Collections that were previously Not Partitioned, fix for this is being released shortly. Meanwhile, the suggested workaround using the SDK will work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with **`ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync`** ?

```
try 
{
    await _client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(...);
} 
catch(DocumentClientException dex) when (dex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict) 
{ 
    await _client.ReplaceStoredProcedureAsync(...);  
}
```

Related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299815/saving-testing-stored-procedures-triggers-maybe-user-defined-functions-for-p)

Comment: yes, I can and will try.  Although at the moment, I am using the Data Explorer in the portal and was hoping that I could just develop a simple stored procedure right there without using the .NET API.

Comment: What is the recommended way of developing CosmosDB stored procedures?  Should I be using Visual Studio Code?